# cannot get a simple foreign key setup with Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

```
The goal is:
The db will have a handful of "plans" that can be used across multiple customers.
Each customer can have only a single plan associated with them at a time. Think of this as your "scription plan". 
The vanilla SQL below works to create this enforces that we cannot delete a plan that is associated with
at least 1 customer. I have not been able to recreate this simple fKey setup in Sequelize. 

For berevity just plat of the DDL:

CREATE TABLE customers (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  planId int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE plans (
  planId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (planId) 
)
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_customers_planId FOREIGN KEY (planId)
REFERENCES plans (planId);
```

I've read the creating associations and advanced associates sections fo the version 6 reference.
I tried hasOne, belongsTo, belongsToMany, and using the through option etc.
I know the through option is for creating a linking table but was just testing to understand how this method works.
db is the exported database object.
None of these do what the above SQL does.

```
  db.Plans.User = db.Plans.belongsTo(db.Customer);
  db.Customer.Plans = db.Customer.hasOne(db.Plans, { foreignKey: db.Plans.planId });
  db.Plans.belongsToMany(db.Customer, { through: 'customerplans' });
  db.Customer.hasOne(db.Plans, { through: 'customerplans' });
```

Comment: You definitely need to use `belongsTo` from `Customer` to `Plans`, i.e. `db.Customer.belongsTo(db.Plans);` and if you need you can define the counterpart association from the `Plans` side: `db.Plans.hasOne(db.Customer`

Answer (score 0):

you can use foriegn key to setup the relation
Customers.belongsTo(Plans, {
foreignKey: 'planId'
})

Plans.hasMany(Customers, {
foreignKey: 'planId'
})

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Still not getting the key. Dropped the tables, changed, and ran the code:
`db.Customers.belongsTo(db.Plans, { foreignKey: 'planId' });
db.Plans.hasMany(db.Customers, { foreignKey: 'planId' });`

The tables are created ok but customers does not have expected fkey. The expected key would look like:
ALTER TABLE customers
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_customers_planId FOREIGN KEY (planId)
REFERENCES plans (planId);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Hope this helps anyone else facing this problem.

1. Added the following to the customer model for the planId column.

```
    planId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'Plans',
        key: 'planId',
      },
    },
```

2. Changed the order of creation in my db module to:

```
db.Plans = require('../data/plans.model')(sequelize);
db.Customers = require('../data/customers.model')(sequelize);
```

Note: This model change worked WITHOUT the need to have the following lines.

```
db.Plans.hasMany(db.Customers, { foreignKey: 'planId' });
db.Customers.belongsTo(db.Plans, { foreignKey: 'planId' });
```